# External Service Call - CalloutException

Tags: callout, soap

We have an implementation where we call an external matching web service. When the records that i send are many, i get the following error: System.CalloutExceptionLine 429The following exception has occurred: Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html'

I have checked that the xml from Salesforce is the whole file that should be sent (not cut). However, when the file reaches apache, it is already cut. What could be the problem? Is there a threshold limit?

Comment: What is the length of an outbound request? Can you post the message here?

Comment: Hi kurunve, you mean the length of the XML file ? If yes, it is 1,24 MB (1.301.777 byte)

Comment: What are you using to create the SOAP callout? Is it based on WSDL2Apex, or did you hand craft the XML payload?

Comment: Hi Daniel. it is based on WSDL2Apex. Probably it was the Web Application Firewall that was cutting the XML file! Problem seems to be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue seems to be solved. It was because of the Web Application Firewall that was cutting the XML File!